# backbone.js router Pushstates & Root

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a page `http://www.domain.com/user/123`, where `123` is the user_id for a particular user. There is a tabbed interface, and clicking on the tab should update the address bar with a new URL.

**Example:** Clicking on `<a href="likes" data-toggle="tab">Likes</a>` should update the address bar to `http://www.domain.com/user/123/likes`

**Problem:** I am trying to implement pushstates in backbone.js, but I can't seem to get the URL right when using `app.navigate()`. I tried setting the `root` attribute in the router using `Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: "/user/" });` which gives me the root as `http://www.domain.com/user/`. How can I add the user_id to the end of `root`? ie. `http://www.domain.com/user/123/`

```
//Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'likes',
        'likes': 'likes',
    },

    likes: function() {
        console.log('fn likes');
        $('#tab_likes"').show();
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: "/user/" });

$(function() {
    // Update address bar URL
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
        app.navigate(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
    });

});
```

---

### Updated Code

How can I update the `root` attribute of `Backbone.history` after grabbing the `user_id` from the url? The current method shown below does not work

```
// Router

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        ':user_id/likes': 'likes',
        ':user_id/': 'likes'
    },

    set_user_id: function($user_id) {
        this.user_id = $user_id;
        // ADD SOME CODE TO CHANGE Backbone.history's root attribute
    },

    likes: function($user_id) {
        console.log('fn likes');
        this.set_user_id($user_id);
        $('#tab_likes"').show();
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ 
    pushState: true, 
    root: '/user/' + app.user_id + '/'  // app.user_id is undefined at the time this is called
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your routes with a parameter to capture the variable user id, i.e.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        ':user/likes': 'likes',
    },

    likes: function(user) {
        console.log(user, 'fn likes');
        $('#tab_likes"').show();
    }
});
```

See the Backbone [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) for more info.
Needless to say that your `href` should be changed accordingly, i.e. `href="123/likes"`.

Finally, in order to not only save the url in history but also trigger the route you need to navigate as such:

```
app.navigate(e.target.getAttribute('href'), true);
```

Comment: Instead of changing the `href`s to include the `user_id`, is it possible to change the `root` attribute of `Backbone.history` after the router has gotten the value of `:user`? *Updated Code in original post*

Comment: No the root should be a constant. But presumably your backbone view has access to the user model and hence its id

Answer (score 0):

`navigate` requires a `trigger` option to be set if you want it to actually fire the route handler (as opposed to just update the URL). From the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/):

> Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call navigate in order to update the URL. If you wish to also call the route function, set the trigger option to true.

So, to get the `console.log` debug to at least work, try this:

```
app.navigate(e.target.getAttribute('href'), true);
```